# when you must implement `Serializable` in quarkus

Tags: quarkus

It is best practice to avoid serialization as much as one can.

What are the serialization requirements in quarkus?

Must I implement `Serializable` for

- `@ApplicationScoped`, `@SessionScoped`, ..
- `@Entity` (composite keys) or PanacheEntities
- or any bean/class which uses **quarkus caching providers**?

Quarkus only runs on a single node. Quarkus does not make use of any passivation/replication for beans, or? Arc is not capable of doing that, or? For example, according to CDI, a session must be a passivating scope, but in ARC the story is different, or?

Will quarkus container throw an error on missing Serializable beans during compiling or deployment?

The question is: 
Are there any requirements when or on which beans/entities to implement Serializable in quarkus environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Neither CDI beans or entities requires serialization.

Comment: Thx. Your answer is different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265908/applicationscoped-must-be-serializable

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html: "Beans that use **session**, **application**, or conversation scope **must be serializable**, but beans that use request scope do not have to be serializable." Quarkus supports session and application scoped beans. But quarkus beans (and not CDI-beans) does not need to be serializable even for application or request scoped. Am I right?